# Disable cmake's "reconfigure during build" functionality

Tags: cmake, ninja

We are using cmake with ninja as the generated build system.

Cmake has a feature where the generated build will also check if the cmake inputs themselves are out of date, which will trigger a call back into cmake to reconfigure before the build proceeds. E.g., if you call `ninja` but some `CMakeLists.txt` has been modified, `ninja` notice and calls `cmake` with a special `--reconfigure-during-build` argument or something like that.

This doesn't work in our case because it loses arguments passed to the original cmake invocation. Is there some way to disable it? An error would be fine.

Comment: "it loses arguments passed to the original cmake invocation"... no it doesn't, not unless your project forcibly overwrites them in the cache or reads from the environment without caching the result. In either case, you have a bug.

Comment: @AlexReinking - perhaps I should say "it _may_ lose...". One common scenario IME is that it detects a change in properties due to the different calling context and so flushes the existing cmake cache and  reconfigures.

Comment: "A change in properties due to the different calling context"... which properties? What do you mean by "calling context"? CMake/Ninja does not sniff the environment when deciding whether or not to regenerate the build system. It looks at the timestamps of your input files, and anything marked CONFIGURE_DEPENDS (whether via file(GLOB) or configure_file or set_property). Even when it does this, it doesn't "flush" the cache.

Comment: An example would be that the `PATH` is set in a certain way when calling cmake expllicitly, which won't be set when ninja reconfigures during the build. I'm not suggesting that this is what causes reconfigure to occur in the first place, that can be something as simple as something minor changing (like an update timestamp on a `CMakeLists.txt` or a changed value for a property passed to `configure_file` or similar) - but it's what causes a problem when configure does re-occur.

Comment: About flushing the cache, I'm not sure of the exact condition, but cmake emits a warning even like "oh, XYZ has changed, we are clearing your cmake cache" or something similar.